# Can clang-format align variable or macro assignments in columns?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, clang, clang-format

Is it possible to have clang-format align variable assignments in columns? For example:

```
int someInteger             = 42;
std::string someString      = "string";
const unsigned someUnsigned = 42;

#define SOME_INTEGER        42
#define SOME_STRING_LITERAL "string"
#define SOME_CONSTANT       42

enum Enum {
    ONE   = 1,
    TWO   = 2,
    THREE = 3,
    FOUR  = 4,
    FIVE  = 5,
    SIX   = 6,
    SEVEN = 7
};
```

is more readable than:

```
int someInteger = 42;
const unsigned someUnsigned = 42;
std::string someString = "string";

#define SOME_INTEGER 42
#define SOME_STRING_LITERAL "string"
#define SOME_CONSTANT 42

enum Enum {
    ONE = 1,
    TWO = 2,
    THREE = 3,
    FOUR = 4,
    FIVE = 5,
    SIX = 6,
    SEVEN = 7
};
```

I realize that it may not be practical for clang-format to always do this, but when code as already been manually formatted like said code, it would be nice for clang-format to leave the formatting in place.

Comment: [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) has option for that, but not clang-format.

Comment: It's shocking to me that it doesn't support this. Basically makes clang format unusable IMO.

Comment: uncrustify's corresponding option is: align_pp_define_span

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like 3.7 supports something like this (haven't tested yet).

From the [docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

> AlignConsecutiveAssignments (bool)
>   If true, aligns consecutive assignments.
>
> This will align the assignment operators of consecutive lines. This will result in formattings like code int aaaa = 12; int b = 23; int ccc = 23; endcode

(sic)

Comment: @syvex, did you have to do anything special to get this working please? I get `error: unknown key 'AlignConsecutiveAssignments'`

Comment: This actually doesn't work for preprocessor macros. I'm currently trying to add this as a separate option, see the latest commit on this branch https://github.com/eriknyquist/clang/tree/align_defines

Comment: Did Eriks commit ever make it to clang? It is ridiculous they have no option to align macros. Why is it taking so long to review and accept?

Comment: @ErikNyquist Did you get anywhere getting that into LLVM?

Comment: No, still open for review. There's just been a lot of churn, if you look over that link I posted to the review you'll see all the changes that have been requested (and that I have implemented). Then there was silence for a long, long time, and someone's just come back in the last month and essentially asked for the whole thing to be reworked, and I just don't have the time/energy anymore.....

Comment: Looks like now there's also `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations`.

Answer (score 3):

Clang-format does not have any option to do this.

If you want to tell clang-format to leave certain lines alone, you can make it do so with `// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on` comments.

Comment: @syvex What version are you using? It looks like it might be a new feature since the 3.5 release.

Answer (score 2):

For macros: looks like you will be able to accomplish this once clang 10 is released, by adding `AlignConsecutiveMacros: true` to you `.clang-format`

https://reviews.llvm.org/D28462

Answer (score 1):

I tested it using https://github.com/mattga/ClangFormat-Xcode/tree/clang_3.7 which is branch of ClangFormat-Xcode supporting 3.7.

I could format a = 9999; type list as I wanted by option

> AlignConsecutiveAssignments = true

. But definitions were not aligned.
Is there any indication to align them?

Comment: AlignConsecutiveDeclarations may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this options:AlignConsecutiveMacros: true
ref:https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html
support llvm version: >=10.0